# Is it possible to derive an upper bound for the given quantity, under this scenario?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Fix a positive integer $r > 1$.  Let $a$ and $b$ be positive integers.

Suppose that I have a strictly increasing sequence of rational numbers

$$\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^r < \left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^{r-1} < \left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^{r-2} < \ldots < \frac{a}{b}$$

with the added constraint

$$\frac{a}{b} < 1 < \frac{a^r}{b}.$$

Here is my question: Will it be possible to derive a *(purely numerical) upper bound* for the following quantity?

$$\frac{a^r}{b}$$

If the answer to my question is *NO*, what *additional* conditions on $a$, $b$ and $r$ would suffice to guarantee the existence of such an *upper bound* for $\displaystyle\frac{a^r}{b}$?

Thank you!

Comment: Oops, I missed out on one particularly important detail - editing my question now to include this omission.

Comment: The answer to the first part seems obviously no as you can select the numerator to be arbitrarily large and the denominator to be marginally larger.  The second question seems too open, depending on what conditions I chose I can get almost any desired bound!

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Macavity.  As an example of a (possible) answer that I'm looking for, note that necessarily, it is not true that $b^{r-1} < 1$, because then we have $1 < {\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)}^r$ which violates my assumptions.

Comment: At any rate, can you write out your comment into an actual answer @Macavity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detailing my comment a bit more...

Given positive integers $a, b > 0$ and $m>n$, we have
$$\dfrac{a}{b} < 1 \implies \left(\dfrac{a}{b}\right)^m < \left(\dfrac{a}{b}\right)^n$$
So all we have to ensure is that the rational number is less than $1$, the sequence will automatically be increasing.

For the upper bound, note that given any large $M > 1$ and fixed $r> 1$, we can choose $a = M-1, b = M$ so that
$$\displaystyle \frac{a}{b} = \frac{M-1}{M} < 1 < M < \frac{(M-1)^r}{M} = \frac{a^r}{b}$$
Thus we can always choose the rational number to satisfy all the conditions and beat any given bound.  Hence there is no upper bound for $\dfrac{a^r}{b}$.

---

"Additional conditions" is too open a phrase - for e.g. a bit trivially, the additional condition could be that $a^r \le 100\cdot b$, which would ensure $100$ is the upper bound.  So you need to say what kind of conditions are permissible.

Comment: Thank you for including further details in your answer @Macavity!